# Running script on system start as given user

Tags: scripting, startup, non-root-user

I have a small script on a dev/staging server that runs services inside `tmux`. The script just creates a few sessions with a few windows each in which various services are running.

How can I make this script run each time the system starts after reboot? I would like to have this script run as specified user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way is to put a command like `su - john -c "bla"` in `/etc/rc.local` (or whatever variant your distro uses.

Comment: If you want this to be something that exists even if the user closes it then using a daemon monitoring or runlevel/init tool is likely a good idea also.

Comment: Yes, I think I should setup init.d scripts for this.

Comment: Above comments is very true. Also remember that if the command run doesn't return, it will hang your rc.local.

Comment: Unless you use `&`.

Answer (score 1):

A more conventional way would be to add a line like this to `/etc/crontab`

```
@reboot USERNAME    COMMAND TO RUN
```

`/etc/crontab` is:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```